# Report of Accounts without Leads

Tags: account, lead-conversion, analytics, custom-reports

Is there a way to create a Report of Accounts that do not have a related Lead? It can be done in SOQL:

`SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT ConvertedAccountId FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted = true)`

But Cross Filters do not allow you to choose Lead as a related object and nor do Custom Report Types.

Comment: if you ad a custom field on Account `wasCreatedByLeadConversion` that you set in Lead Mappings, then you could do this, retrospectively would require data migration